ImportError when importing from parent directory
I'm encountering an error when running script.py in VSCode using Ctrl+F5, which results in the following traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\Desktop\sample\main\script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ..utils import say_hi
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package


My project structure is as follows:
└── sample
    └── .venv
    └── main
        └── script.py
        └── __init__.py
    └── utils.py
    └── __init__.py

Both __init__.py are empty to mark the directories as packages.
Here's the content of utils.py:
def say_hi():
    print("Hello World")

And here's script.py:
from ..utils import say_hi
say_hi()

You can find the source code at: GitHub Repository.
Why does it occur here, and how can I resolve it?
I attempted to resolve the ImportError by converting directories into packages with empty __init__.py files, expecting this to enable successful relative imports within my project structure. However, even after this modification, the ImportError persisted when running script.py in VSCode using Ctrl+F5, indicating an attempted relative import with no known parent package.

What do you have Ctrl+F5 configured as? (i.e. what command, if you look in your keybinding settings)

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/4383597/1348195 you can import from a parent of a package but not of the entry point basically.

I didn't change the default configuration for my Python environment and VS Code.
  "key": "ctrl+f5",
  "command": "workbench.action.debug.run",
  "when": "debuggersAvailable && debugState != 'initializing'"
}``` @wjandrea

@BenjaminGruenbaum I prefer not to modify the search path; instead, I aim to follow best practices by using packages and relative imports.

Right, so put a file at the top level in the folder utils is to call script.py - and use that as the entry point

@BenjaminGruenbaum: And run with python3 -m script, not python3 path/to/script.py.

I don't have a utils folder. Please illustrate the file structure.

I suggest editing the source code in the GitHub repository as the optimal solution. The code is extremely concise and minimal.
